# Spoofing video card vendorid and deviceid

Tags: graphics-card, spoofing, vendor-id

I was wondering if there's some way to spoof my video card vendorid and deviceid, so that I can run a software that runs only for certain ids. Is `devcon.exe` something I can use? I've read about 3D-Analyzer, but this executable I want to run only runs through a launcher, so 3D-Analyzer is useless for this.

Answer (score 0):

at first what is your graphic card name ? because there is a way that u can change your graphic card vendor id and device id but u have to edit your graphic card original bios , here is 1 example of that : 
https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/change-device-id-from-sapphire-radeon-6770-to-5770.152315/
but newer card use new version of bios that u can only make an backup of that and when u want to update or flash your backup bios into the graphic card it will check hash of the bios so if u edit the bios there is no chance to flash it into the graphic card , so have that chance to do that if your graphic card is old one that can be flashed with edited bios file and remember if the application u want to use need some special graphic card maybe there is hardware not just software i mean even after you changed your vendor id and device id u still can't run that application because the application needs to use hardware features not just the device id and vendor id to detect you have that graphic card or not .